# GooglePlay v19 emulator throwing "E/EGL_emulation﹕ Failed to establish connection with the host" among others

Tags: android, android-emulator, opengl-es-2.0, google-play-services

So I've got an emulator that is throwing a lot of exceptions while loading. I'll post the stack trace at the bottom because its so large.

The emulator started doing this out of no where, my non Google Play API emulator is NOT doing this. But I can't test my google Maps app on that other one. So I'm at a stand still.

I've: 1. Wiped emulator info
2. Deleted the emulator (all of them) and re-installed
3. I've uninstalled the whole V19 SDKs, wiped android studio cache, restarted computer and then tried again.

Any steps that can be taken to work out Google Play API/openGL issues?

```
08-26 18:36:11.620        38-38/? E/logwrapper﹕ executing /system/bin/e2fsck failed: No such file or directory
08-26 18:36:11.670        41-41/? E/logwrapper﹕ executing /system/bin/e2fsck failed: No such file or directory
08-26 18:36:15.300        49-49/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ hwcomposer module not found
08-26 18:36:17.280        49-71/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-26 18:36:18.680       52-113/? E/AudioFlinger﹕ no wake lock to update!
08-26 18:36:18.740        52-52/? E/AudioFlinger﹕ int android::load_audio_interface(const char*, audio_hw_device_t**) couldn't load audio hw module audio.r_submix (No such file or directory)
08-26 18:36:46.050      308-308/? E/logwrapper﹕ executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
08-26 18:36:46.090      309-309/? E/logwrapper﹕ executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
08-26 18:36:46.110      310-310/? E/logwrapper﹕ executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
08-26 18:36:46.170      311-311/? E/logwrapper﹕ executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
08-26 18:36:46.240      312-312/? E/logwrapper﹕ executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
08-26 18:36:46.260      313-313/? E/logwrapper﹕ executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
08-26 18:36:46.320      314-314/? E/logwrapper﹕ executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
08-26 18:37:56.970        50-50/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
08-26 18:37:56.970        50-50/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
08-26 18:38:02.660        50-50/? E/EmojiFactory_jni﹕ Failed to load libemoji.so: dlopen failed: library "libemoji.so" not found
08-26 18:38:27.180        50-50/? E/﹕ Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
08-26 18:38:27.180        50-50/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ Failed to establish connection with the host
```

There are over 1000 lines (I think ~1800 based on the results at the bottom)

```
08-26 18:38:32.920        50-50/? E/﹕ Failed to connect to host (QemuPipeStream)!!!
08-26 18:38:32.920        50-50/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ Failed to establish connection with the host
08-26 18:38:33.810      406-406/? E/PowerManagerService-JNI﹕ Couldn't load power module (No such file or directory)
08-26 18:38:34.590        49-71/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-26 18:40:49.580      406-406/system_process E/ConsumerIrService﹕ Can't open consumer IR HW Module, error: -2
08-26 18:40:49.610      406-406/system_process E/libsuspend﹕ Error opening /sys/power/autosleep: No such file or directory
08-26 18:40:50.440      406-457/system_process E/EventHub﹕ could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
08-26 18:40:50.550      406-457/system_process E/EventHub﹕ could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
08-26 18:40:53.550      406-406/system_process E/MobileDataStateTracker﹕ default: Ignoring feature request because could not acquire PhoneService
08-26 18:40:53.550      406-406/system_process E/MobileDataStateTracker﹕ default: Could not enable APN type "default"
08-26 18:40:55.850      406-406/system_process E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: locksettings
08-26 18:40:57.320      406-406/system_process E/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_restorecon:  Error restoring context for /cache/backup (No such file or directory)
08-26 18:40:57.320      406-406/system_process E/LocalTransport﹕ SELinux restorecon failed for /cache/backup
08-26 18:41:02.520      479-479/com.android.systemui E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Lock.ogg
08-26 18:41:02.540      479-479/com.android.systemui E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Unlock.ogg
08-26 18:41:35.420      406-421/system_process E/NetdConnector﹕ NDC Command {1 bandwidth enable} took too long (4435ms)
08-26 18:41:36.060      479-479/com.android.systemui E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
08-26 18:41:36.060      479-479/com.android.systemui E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
08-26 18:41:36.340      479-479/com.android.systemui E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
08-26 18:41:36.450      406-421/system_process E/NetdConnector﹕ NDC Command {2 firewall disable} took too long (914ms)
08-26 18:41:37.030      406-421/system_process E/NetdConnector﹕ NDC Command {3 bandwidth gettetherstats} took too long (507ms)
08-26 18:41:37.050      479-479/com.android.systemui E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
08-26 18:41:37.930      406-421/system_process E/NetdConnector﹕ NDC Command {4 bandwidth setglobalalert 2097152} took too long (827ms)
08-26 18:41:39.230      406-421/system_process E/NetdConnector﹕ NDC Command {5 firewall disable} took too long (1140ms)
08-26 18:41:41.480      479-479/com.android.systemui E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
08-26 18:42:18.660      406-421/system_process E/FlpHardwareProvider﹕ Error hw_get_module 'flp': -2
08-26 18:42:18.780      406-421/system_process E/FlpHardwareProvider﹕ Error hw_get_module 'flp': -2
08-26 18:42:36.010      406-421/system_process E/ActivityManager﹕ ANR in system
    PID: 406
    Reason: Executing service com.android.location.fused/.FusedLocationService
    Load: 5.13 / 2.2 / 0.94
    CPU usage from 0ms to 14862ms later:
    25% 406/system_server: 14% user + 10% kernel / faults: 1812 minor
    17% 640/com.google.process.location: 13% user + 3.3% kernel / faults: 1814 minor
    5.6% 479/com.android.systemui: 4% user + 1.6% kernel / faults: 597 minor
    5.5% 49/surfaceflinger: 2.5% user + 3% kernel / faults: 4 minor
    4.3% 47/debuggerd: 2.1% user + 2.1% kernel / faults: 818 minor
    1.7% 88/bootanimation: 0.5% user + 1.1% kernel
    1.5% 629/com.android.inputmethod.latin: 1.2% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 297 minor
    1.1% 60/adbd: 0.1% user + 1% kernel
    0.6% 670/com.android.settings: 0.3% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 829 minor
    0.3% 26/mtdblock1: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
    0.2% 245/logcat: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
    0.2% 609/android.process.acore: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 22 minor
    0.1% 25/mtdblock0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
    0.1% 663/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 379 minor
    0% 11/kworker/0:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
    0% 37/flush-31:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
    0% 39/jbd2/mtdblock1-: 0% user + 0% kernel
    0% 53/installd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
    +0% 685/<pre-initialized>: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 709/dexopt: 0% user + 0% kernel
    100% TOTAL: 69% user + 30% kernel + 0.2% softirq
    CPU usage from 12763ms to 14050ms later:
    49% 709/dexopt: 47% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 474 minor
    22% 640/com.google.process.location: 22% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
    21% 640/rocess.location: 20% user + 0.9% kernel
    0.9% 650/Compiler: 0.9% user + 0% kernel
    14% 406/system_server: 6.9% user + 7.8% kernel / faults: 16 minor
    13% 421/ActivityManager: 6.9% user + 6% kernel
    1.7% 420/WindowManager: 0% user + 1.7% kernel
    6.9% 49/surfaceflinger: 4.3% user + 2.6% kernel
    3.4% 49/surfaceflinger: 2.6% user + 0.8% kernel
    1.7% 71/Binder_1: 0.8% user + 0.8% kernel
    1.7% 77/DispSync: 1.7% user + 0% kernel
    0.8% 405/Binder_4: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
    5.2% 88/bootanimation: 1.7% user + 3.4% kernel
    5.2% 102/BootAnimation: 1.7% user + 3.4% kernel
    0.8% 60/adbd: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
    0.8% 227/adbd: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
    0.8% 685/<pre-initialized>: 0% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 8 minor
    0.8% 685/re-initialized>: 0% user + 0.8% kernel
    100% TOTAL: 75% user + 24% kernel
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to edit the AVD skin to use “skin with dynamic hardware controls”